# Java : List of Maps when type of values is ArrayList

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist

I'm working on a java project and i want to create a list of Maps that the type of keys is Character and the values are ArrayLists of Characters. I have written something like this :

`List<Map<Character, ArrayList<Character>>>`

but the eclipse says : `Syntax error on token ">>>", VariableDeclarator expected after this token`

How can i do it ? any idea ?

Comment: can you post a bit more code?

Comment: Instead of a `List<Map<Character, ArrayList<Character>>>` I'd write some classes representing your data. After all, Java is an OOP language. You'll get self describing and easy to maintain code. Right now, your heading into a mess.

Comment: can you include the whole line of code where you are declaring `List<Map<Character, ArrayList<Character>>>`?

Comment: I think the compiler error is just informaing you that you need to supply the **name** of the variable.

Answer (score 8):

The compiler is expecting a variable name to comply with Java syntax:

```
List<Map<Character, List<Character>>> myList = 
                              new ArrayList<Map<Character, List<Character>>>();
```

Comment: I might +1 IF this turns out to be the actual issue

Comment: This is correct. You could also have `List<Map<Character, ArrayList<Character>>> myList;` and define `myList` later.

Comment: Why i can't have an array of Maps ? (instead of using List)

Comment: @Kozet - You could use an array of Maps, but it would be much better to use a list.

Comment: You can also use `List<Map<Character, List<Character>>> = new ArrayList<Map<Character, List<Character>>>();`

Answer (score 0):

`List<Map<Character, ArrayList<Character>>> list ;` should be given

see the screen shot below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable as an interface (e.g. `List`) but to create an instance, you must choose an implementation (e.g. `ArrayList`):

`List<Map<Character, ArrayList<Character>>> myList = new ArrayList<Map<Character, ArrayList<Character>>>();`